# Using get_time() to for fstream

Tags: c++

While using **get_time()** to get the value, the first line keeps giving **0** for tm.year while the second line works normally. Could I know what mistakes I have made?

The function is here:

```
void Log_Residental_Price_Index()
{
    std::fstream file;
    file.open("Residental Price Index.csv", std::ios::in);

    struct tm RecordXX = {0};
    std::string line;
    std::string field;

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        std::stringstream line_(line);
        while (getline(line_, field, ','))
        {
            std::stringstream field_(field);
            field_ >> std::get_time(&RecordXX, "%d/%m/%Y");
            std::cout << RecordXX.tm_year << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Content of Residental Price Index.csv:**

```
1/1/1993,90.4,81.3,80.7,74.2,58.1
1/2/1993,90.5,82.6,81.3,74.9,62.2
```

**Output**:

```
1/1/1993,90.4,81.3,80.7,74.2,58.1
0
1/2/1993,90.5,82.6,81.3,74.9,62.2
93
```

Could I know what mistake I have made? I am stuck on this problem for so longgg Thank you so much!

Comment: You should check if parse failed or not. `if (ss.fail()) { std::cout << "Parse failed\n"; } else { std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%c") << '\n'; }` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time

Comment: BTW which compiler are you using?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/orMn3dsr5 - the code fails for GCC 11.3 and works for GCC 12.1.